# Evaluating the output of multiple functions which return True or False

Tags: python-3.x

So I came across this interesting problem.It basically is a lot of functions which return True or False within a function and I want that secondary function to return either True or False based on applying an AND or OR logic to all of the functions within it. I know this is a terrible way to explain so let's see some code which will hopefully explain it better

```py
#this is the first function that return True or False
def f(x):
    if x == 1:
        return True
    elif x == 0:
        return False
#this is the function that takes the first one and I want it to return either True or False based on an AND logic
def g(f):

    f(1)
    f(0)
    f(0)
    f(1)
    f(1)
    f(0)
    f(1)
```

Now I know I can just write the second function with 'and' between all the f(x) functions that I call but that  seems very ugly and so I want something that will just evaluate all of these and return me a value. I don't enough experience with writing methods which take in multiple inputs and also multiple inputs that vary so I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `all` and a comprehension over the variable arguments (`*args`) of the funtion:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     if x == 1:
...         return True
...     elif x == 0:
...         return False
... 
>>> def g(f, *args):
...     return all(f(x) for x in args)
... 
>>> g(f, 1, 0, 0, 1)
False
>>> g(f, 1, 1, 1)
True
```

Comment: Concise and effective, I dig it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the existing [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#all) function that is equivalent to a logical AND:

```py
def f(x):
  return x < 5

all((f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)))
```

Now concerning function `g` you can do this (for example):

```py
def g(f, inputs):
  for i in inputs:
    yield f(i)

all(g(f, range(5)))
```

Here you can replace `range(5)` with any of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`, `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`, and many more (ie. any iterable).

Note that a function similar to `g` also exists in python, it's called [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map), you could use it this way:

```py
all(map(f, range(5))) # More or less equivalent to all(g(f, range(5)))
```

You could also directly make use a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) (an alternative to the [`yield` *generator*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) form):

```py
all(f(i) for i in range(5))
```

Which one of this solution is the best really depend on the use case and on your personal preferences (even if the last one is probably the one you will most commonly see).

Comment: Great answer man, kudos for the effort but it was also really long and I thought anyone coming across this problem will want a quicker solution so I choose the shorter one. But your details are great though and they are very helpful. I hope you don't hold it against me.

Comment: No problem, the most pythonic solution probably is `all(map(f, ...))` but the one most people would probably write (and therefore prefer to read) is `all(f(i) for i in ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

For `AND` function, you can use python's [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), and for `OR` function, you can use python's [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

```
>>> all([True, False])
False
>>> all([True, True])
True
>>> any([True, False])
True
>>> any([True, True])
True
>>> any([False, False])
False
```

Just append all your outputs in a list, and evaluate `all` or `any`, so considering function `f` you defined

```
print(all([f(1),f(1)]))
print(all([f(0),f(0)]))
print(any([f(1), f(0)]))
print(any([f(0), f(0)]))
#True
#False
#True
#False
```